# How does the Little Sister Madness mechanic work in Dragon Star Varnir?

Tags: dragon-star-varnir

What exactly is it that increases the Little Sisters' madness levels in Dragon Star Varnir? Picking up chests, number of battles, time spent, or what?

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question here because I scoured the internet for the answer before I spent 2 days running experiments to prove the answer. The definitive answer is distance traveled, and nothing else. If you walk for 2 minutes and 15 seconds, the sisters will go from green to blue. Another 2:15 for blue to yellow, 4:30 to red, 6:45 to purple, and another 6:45 until they disappear. Feeding them 5 dragon meat "heals" approximately one and a half blue states, that is, about 3:30 worth of walking, though it cannot go below zero.

For a much deeper dive on this and the methodology I used to find this out, and some advice on how to mitigate this and stay below red the entire game but still get every core and chest, check here: https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/ps4/243641-dragon-star-varnir/faqs/79247